# Puppeteer get page.content with recursive iteration to get all result of paginate list

Tags: puppeteer

I want to get all results of paginate list of data with puppeteer.

If I make a for cycle I give this error:

```
(node:54961) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Cannot find context with specified id undefined

(node:54961) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var sleep = require('sleep');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();

console.log('start');
page.on('console', (...args) => console.log('PAGE LOG:', ...args));

await page.goto('pageUrl');
var num = 0;
for(var i=0; i< 10; i++){
    var content = await page.content();
    console.log('we have content of page '+num);
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFileSync("htmls/"+num+".html", content);
    console.log("The file of page "+num+" was saved!");

    var sleepSecond = getRandomInt(20,40);
    console.log("We are waiting "+ sleepSecond + " seconds");
    sleep.sleep(sleepSecond);

    var inputElement = await page.$('a.next');
    await inputElement.click();
    console.log('Click on next');
    sleepSecond = getRandomInt(40,80);
    console.log("We are waiting "+ sleepSecond + " seconds");
    sleep.sleep(sleepSecond);
    num +=15;
}

browser.close();
})();
```

So how solve this error and how transform a for cycle in recursive cycle?

Answer (score -1):

I found wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch solves it. I kept finding `.then()` & `.catch()` examples, but this [post](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) had an example that almost made it too simple.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('start');
        page.on('console', (...args) => console.log('PAGE LOG:', ...args));
        await page.goto('pageUrl');
        var num = 0;
        for(var i=0; i< 10; i++){
            var content = await page.content();
            console.log('we have content of page '+num);
            var fs = require('fs');
            fs.writeFileSync("htmls/"+num+".html", content);
            console.log("The file of page "+num+" was saved!");

            var sleepSecond = getRandomInt(20,40);
            console.log("We are waiting "+ sleepSecond + " seconds");
            sleep.sleep(sleepSecond);

            var inputElement = await page.$('a.next');
            await inputElement.click();
            console.log('Click on next');
            sleepSecond = getRandomInt(40,80);
            console.log("We are waiting "+ sleepSecond + " seconds");
            sleep.sleep(sleepSecond);
            num +=15;
        }
        browser.close();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: That's not a solution. The logs come from the fact that the script creates promises which ends up being rejected without an error handler, which may put your code in an unpredictable state. Simply wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch block is actually a pretty bad idea as it will catch any sort of error that you may not want to ignore. Check out the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) for guidance on promise rejection.